# ASP.NET Core module not in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-express

I am keep getting [500.19(0x8007000d)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) error when running my .NET core project through IIS Express. 
After a bit digging, it looks like IIS doesn't recognize `<aspNetCore>` as a valid element in the web.config.

Here are the things I've tried:

- installed URL rewrite module as someone suggested installed
- `AspNetCoreModule` throgh here:
  https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.5.
- installed .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle.

I've tried adding it as a managed module and put the path for `AspNetCoreModule`, but looks like it doesn't fix the issue. Enable stdoutLog doesn't work, because it simply won't generate any log file.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to host your .NET Core App under IIS or IIS Express? For IIS Express I don't think you need hosting bundle

Comment: Like the other comment indicated, your first task would be learning what is IIS and what is IIS Express. To confirm if you do hit the ASP.NET Core module missing issue, run Jexus Manager https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/oob-500.html If you happen to meet another 500.19 (there are many variations), then the solution would be completely different.

Comment: Thank you guys, my app is hosted under IIS.

Comment: After a few setups for .net core projects, I realized what I've missed is run 'iisreset' command after the module is installed...

Answer (score 1):

I got it working finally. Because all my website is under the default website, I went to install `AspNetCoreModule` module for the default website.

After it was installed, I noticed a change in the web.config under the default website. At the same time, `AspNetCoreModule` module is also listed as Native module in the module section.

The real error message is web.config was trying to install AspNetCoreModule, but it is already installed. Then I deleted the `<modules>` section in the web.config under the default website and it worked...

The website used to work before I turned off/on windows IIS features. Really not sure what caused this...

Comment: > I went to install AspNetCoreModule module for the default website

How did you do this?

Comment: @AlexDresko Open Default Web Site -> Modules -> Add Managed Module(or Configure Native Modules, I can't recall exactly which option I selected)

Comment: I must be struggling with a slightly different issue. AspNetCoreModule should be in that list, I believe. It's not on the computer I'm working on. Maybe I should check a working computer.

Comment: @AlexDresko, yes that module will appear in the list after running the command **'iisreset'**. Otherwise, IIS has trouble identifying that module, I've noticed this couple of times now.

Comment: You should accept your answer. But every steps you made changed the error page slightly (Initially no ASP.NET Core module, so a miserable 500.19, expected. Then you seemed to have added ASP.NET Core module to server level, which triggered another 500.19 as it duplicated with web.config. So your final removal from web.config resolved all.) So I rather say it isn't a real answer to the real problem with clear enough analysis, and you really shouldn't register ASP.NET Core at server level for all web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing the core server hosting  from the add remove program did the trick -
It seems like IIS was installed or changed after core windows server hosting. According to Microsoft is such case you need to repair the hosting bundle

Answer (score -2):

Add Native module with path C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll